# Java Socket to find real client IP Address

Tags: java

I am trying to get Real Client IP address using a Java applet. I want to eventually use it in a PHP script, to help with security and authentication. None of the PHP methods will work as the various HTTP headers are not available and can be spoofed easily.

So I am adopting the method suggested in [Get the correct local IP address from java applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510526/get-the-correct-local-ip-adress-from-java-applet) and http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=15832

However, I cannot compile my simple Applet. I am new to Java, so am a little confused.

Code is:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SimpleSocketClient
{
    public SimpleSocketClient()
    {
        try
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket("89.185.150.131", 80);
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            System.out.println("Error in initialising the network - " + exc.toString());
        }

        InetAddress addr = socket.getLocalAddress();
        String hostAddr = addr.getHostAddress();
        System.out.println("Addr: " + hostAddr);

    }

}
```

When compiling, I get the following error:

```
C:\mba>javac SimpleSocketClient.java
SimpleSocketClient.java:18: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable socket
location: class SimpleSocketClient
        InetAddress addr = socket.getLocalAddress();
                           ^
1 error

C:\mba>
```

Thanks

Comment: *"I am trying to get Real Client IP address using a Java applet."* Why?

Comment: The answer is correct - I strongly encourage you to accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Your `socket` variable is declared inside a `try` block and is therefore not accessible outside that block. You can make a slight change by either pushing all code inside the `try`:

```
public SimpleSocketClient()
{
    try
    {
        Socket socket = new Socket("89.185.150.131", 80);

        InetAddress addr = socket.getLocalAddress();
        String hostAddr = addr.getHostAddress();
        System.out.println("Addr: " + hostAddr);
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in initialising the network - " + exc.toString());
    }
}
```

Or by declaring `socket` outside the `try`:

```
public SimpleSocketClient()
{
    Socket socket = null;
    try
    {
        socket = new Socket("89.185.150.131", 80);
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        System.out.println("Error in initialising the network - " + exc.toString());
    }
    if(socket != null) {
        InetAddress addr = socket.getLocalAddress();
        String hostAddr = addr.getHostAddress();
        System.out.println("Addr: " + hostAddr);
    }
}
```