# How to get client IP address with the help of the applet?

Tags: java, applet, ip-address

I've tried to get the IP address of client with the help of socket but i'm not getting the exact result.

Comment: try the answers in this SO post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324466/finding-user-ip-address

Comment: this answer also looks promising - http://stackoverflow.com/a/6692446/3748701

Comment: *"I've tried to get the IP address of client.."* Why?