# how to get ip behind NAT using php?

Tags: php, wamp, lamp

Is it possible to retrieve IP behind NAT in PHP?
I am using `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]` for getting IP address of the client. It's not giving exact IP address of the client which is in behind NAT.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, not possible. NAT means Network Address *Translation* - the IP address of the packets is rewritten at the NAT device, so the public IP address is the only one, as far as your server knows.

However, you can employ some tricks - such as checking for the internal IP address using a Java Applet. See this: [Get the correct local IP address from java applet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510526/get-the-correct-local-ip-adress-from-java-applet)

Comment: (I'm not sure for what you'd need the internal IP address, anyway; and note that multiple nested NATs are possible - so that a computer may be seen e.g. as 192.168.0.153, 10.53.0.1, 192.168.42.12 and 1.2.3.4, depending on the network topology)

Comment: I need internal IP to trace systems inside near by network. Here they are using multiple NAT for network.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible to get the IP behind a NAT using HTTP and php.

Answer (score 2):

No. PHP only sees the external IP.

> 'REMOTE_ADDR'
>       The IP address from which the user is viewing the current page.

Answer (score 2):

if they are using proxy you can use

```
       $real_ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
```

otherwise, it is not possible

Comment: $real_ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] is used for proxy detection right?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the private address of client and usually you don't care to see it beacuse you can't access that. Even if it used a proxy, sometimes you may get address by:

```
 $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
```