# JSP: new Socket ("www", 80); stopped working after years of working OK

Tags: java, jsp, sockets, tomcat6

In a JSP app, in Tomcat, the following code used to produce the whole address of the page (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1510642/1598390)):

```
String myUrl = "no network";
try {
    Socket s = new Socket("www", 80);
    myUrl = "http://"+s.getLocalAddress().getHostAddress()+":"+request.getLocalPort()+request.getRequestURI();
    s.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
} finally {
}
```

After that `miUrl` would have the folowing value (not the real IP addr): `http://111.101.101.2:8080/mypage.jsp`

It has been working for several years.

A week ago `miUrl` began having "no network" as value, indicating that an exception happened.

I issued `ex.printStackTrace()` and is says: `java.net.UnknownHostException: www`

Creating a socked with the literal *"www"* used to work, now out of a sudden it stopped working.

Question:

- What's the technical reason why it worked for years?
- What's the technical reason why it stopped working all of a sudden?
- What would be the best way to programatically produce the whole address of any JSP page, that is not error-prone?

EDIT: It's a file-sharing app, running in the users's workstation, I want users to be able to copy the address to share links with others, and `http://localhost:8080/downloadpage.jsp` (as shown in address field of browser) is no good for sharing. It would help if you show me how to get that same info without the socket hack.

Comment: Did your java version change? container version? OS version? proxy, firewall?

Comment: Perhaps your DNS or hosts file previously resolved `www` and now that record has been removed?

Comment: Why? You shouldn't be creating `Sockets` for this in the first place. Both those pieces of information are in the request. In any case you don't need to know your hostname or port when outputting URLs. Just make it a relative URL, starting with the context name.

Comment: @EJP It's a file-sharing app, running in the users's workstation, I want users to be able to copy the address to share links with others, and `http://localhost:8080/downloadpage.jsp` (as shown in address field of browser) is no good for sharing. It would help if you show me how to get that same info without the socket hack.

Comment: `how to get that same info` you cannot get public external ip address/dns name or it will not work in NAT environment

Comment: @Lashane You mean it's impossible for a JSP page get the IP and port of its server/container? The socket hack used to do exactly that.

Comment: @user1598390 it is impossible to get externally accessible ip/name, because user's local host could be behind NAT/firewall, the only IP/name which you can get for sure - 127.0.0.1/localhost, probably local ip address like 192.168.1.2 and localname, like workstation3

Comment: @Lashane All users are in an intranet.

Comment: @user1598390 then you could use `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getAddress()` instead of socket hack

Comment: Then you should open a socket to a host that actually exists. Clearly `"www"` was some trick of your DNS that has stopped working. Better still, use `InetAddress` to find the 'most public' IP address of your local host, and do it once, and don't open a `Socket` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the IP addr part without using a socket.

```
public String getIP(){
    String ip="no network";
    try {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> n = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
        outmost:
        for (; n.hasMoreElements();)
        {
            NetworkInterface e = n.nextElement();
            Enumeration<InetAddress> a = e.getInetAddresses();
            for (; a.hasMoreElements();)
            {
                InetAddress addr = a.nextElement();             
                if (addr instanceof Inet4Address){ // return the first IPv4 addr (127.0.1.1 is always last)
                    if (addr.isSiteLocalAddress()){
                        ip=addr.getHostAddress();
                        break outmost;
                    }

                }
            }
        }           
    } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
    } catch (SocketException e) {
    } 
    return ip;      
}
```

Then

```
String miUrl = "http://"+getIP()+":"+request.getLocalPort()+request.getRequestURI();
```

Answer (score 2):

Like Beau Grantham said in the comment, there's a decent chance that this is a DNS issue. Try

```
$ ping www
```

and see if it resolves to anything. If you get

```
$ ping www
ping: cannot resolve www: Unknown host
$
```

then that's your issue.

I ran this locally and got:

```
~$ java TestResolve
java.net.UnknownHostException: www
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
    at TestResolve.main(TestResolve.java:7)
```

(I wouldn't expect this to be a hosts file since everybody is able to use the URL. Anyway 'www' is the sort of thing that you'd manage using DNS.)

As far as programmatically generating URLs, try

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
```

if you're OK with a hostname. The other peers can probably resolve that. Otherwise

```
InetAddress localhost = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
InetAddress[] ips = InetAddress.getAllByName(localhost.getHostName());
```

Here you'll get a list of IPs for the host in question, corresponding to different interfaces. You might have to choose one based on the subnet, which presumably you could configure into the app.

Comment: The IPs of users can change over time. It's a file-sharing app, running in the users's workstation, I want users to be able to copy the address to share links with others, and http://localhost:8080/downloadpage.jsp (as shown in address field of browser) is no good for sharing. It would help if you show me how to get that same info without the socket hack.

Comment: OK, got it now. See revision.

Comment: `InetAddress` only returns the users's machine name, which other users cannot resolve, or `127.0.1.1` which doesn't work for sharing links either.

Comment: Also, why "www" pointed to my dynamic IP addr? I got the "www" from this answer some years ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510526/get-the-correct-local-ip-adress-from-java-applet . How come "www" pointed to the IP address of my workstation, given I got the code snippet from the internet and didn't fiddle with DNSs or hosts file ?