# Why do I get different output from within a java applet then from native java?

Tags: java, sockets, applet, channel

I have the following class definition, which extends Applet:

```
public class TestApplet extends Applet {  
  public static void main(String []argv) {
    TestApplet a = new TestApplet();
    InetAddress b = a.justATest();
    if (b != null) {
      System.out.println(b.getHostAddress());
    }
    if (a.hasError()) {
      System.out.println(a.getErrorTrace());
    }
  }

  public InetAddress justATest(String ip) {
    err = null;
    try {
      final DatagramChannel ch = DatagramChannel.open();
      final InetSocketAddress s = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(ip), 53);
      final InetSocketAddress c = new InetSocketAddress((InetAddress)null, 0);

      class testAction implements PrivilegedExceptionAction<Object> {
        public Object run() throws IOException {
          ch.bind(c);
          try {
            ch.connect(s);
          } catch (NoRouteToHostException ex) {
          }
          return null;
        }
      }

      testAction a = new testAction();
      try { 
        AccessController.doPrivileged(a);
      } catch (PrivilegedActionException pae) {
        Exception ex = pae.getException();
        if (ex instanceof IOException) {
          throw (IOException)ex;
        } else { 
          throw (RuntimeException)ex;
        }
      }
      return ((InetSocketAddress)ch.getLocalAddress()).getAddress();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      err = ex;
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

The code simply creates a `DatagramSocket`, binds and "connects" it, and then grabs the local address.  When I run the following on a command line, I get the following output:

```
$ java TestApplet 2001:db8::1
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0
$ java TestApplet 192.0.2.1
192.168.1.3
```

This is expected behavior.  192.168.1.3 is my own address.  The ANY IPv6 address (0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0) is expected because I don't currently have IPv6 access.

Now, when I run the code from a browser with the following code:

```
function deployApplet() {
  dtjava.embed({
      id: 'test-applet',
      url: 'testapplet.jnlp',
      width: 1,
      height: 1,
      placeholder: "appletPlaceholder",
    },
    {},
    {
      onJavascriptReady: function(id) {
        var applet = document.getElementById(id);
        var addr;
        addr = applet.justATest("192.0.2.1");
        if (addr != null) {
          console.log(addr.getHostAddress());
        }
        if (applet.hasError()) {
          console.log(applet.getErrorTrace());
        }
        addr = applet.justATest("2620:db8::1");
        if (addr != null) {
          console.log(addr.getHostAddress());
        }
        if (applet.hasError()) {
          console.log(applet.getErrorTrace());
        }
      },
    }
  );
}
dtjava.addOnloadCallback(deployApplet);
```

The jar file from which the applet is running is signed, and I have the following in the jnlp file:

```
<security>
  <all-permissions />
</security>
```

Without those provisions (and the doPrivileged() wrapper included in the code) I would get a permissions failure.

Now, I run that in the browser and get the following output in the Web console:

```
127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1
```

Any reason why I would get different output when running from the browser environment that from command line?

Note that other than the output of `getLocalAddress()`, the channel appears to behave as expected.  I use this code in a less simplified context to send DNS queries, and there are no other issues (that I can see).  The communication, including `connect()`, `read()`, and `write()` calls, works just fine in the applet.

Comment: Your channel is bound to the wildcard address. It may happen that this is defined differently in the context of standalone and browser embedded.

Comment: May be related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510526/get-the-correct-local-ip-adress-from-java-applet

Comment: Hmm.  Could be, but it seems unlikely both that 127.0.0.1--a designated loopback address--would be used as the wildcard address and that both the IPv4 and IPv6 examples would behave this way, particularly since I can verify IPv4 connectivity.

Comment: Your pointer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510526/get-the-correct-local-ip-adress-from-java-applet was helpful (thanks!).  It indicated that permissions might be the problem.  That surprised me a bit because in other cases an `AccessControlException` was thrown, but in my case, java simply returned 127.0.0.1 when `getLocalAddress()` was called without a `doPrivileged()` block.  I'll add the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently calling `getLocalAddress()` on a `DatagramChannel` also requires being in a privileged block of code.  The behavior is somewhat misleading, as other cases in which there are insufficient permissions to run something in an applet, `AccessControlException` is thrown, but in this case 127.0.0.1 is returned when `getLocalAddress()` is called from an applet outside a `doPrivileged()` block.

So, to fix the code in the original question, the call to `getLocalAddress()` is simply added to the doPrivileged block.  The `justATest()` definition is as follows:

```
  public InetAddress justATest(String ip) {
    err = null;
    try {
      final DatagramChannel ch = DatagramChannel.open();
      final InetSocketAddress s = new InetSocketAddress(InetAddress.getByName(ip), 53);
      final InetSocketAddress c = new InetSocketAddress((InetAddress)null, 0);

      class testAction implements PrivilegedExceptionAction<InetSocketAddress> {
        public InetSocketAddress run() throws IOException {
          ch.bind(c);
          try {
            ch.connect(s);
          } catch (NoRouteToHostException ex) {
          }
          return ((InetSocketAddress)ch.getLocalAddress());
        }
      }

      testAction a = new testAction();
      try {
        return AccessController.doPrivileged(a).getAddress();
      } catch (PrivilegedActionException pae) {
        Exception ex = pae.getException();
        if (ex instanceof IOException) {
          throw (IOException)ex;
        } else {
          throw (RuntimeException)ex;
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      err = ex;
      return null;
    }
  }
```